# How to map a Map<String, String> through annotations?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have POJO in which I need to map a MAP field through annotations. I am trying the below code.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEM_ATTRIBUTE", catalog = "DataSync")
public class ItemAttribute implements Cloneable, Serializable {

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = AttributeValueRange.class) 
    @MapKeyColumn(name="rangeId") 
    @Column(name="value")   
    @CollectionTable(name="ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_RANGE", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ITEM_ID"))
    private Map<String, String> attributeValueRange;
}
```

I have also made a separate class for the Map field. 
Below is the `AttributeValueRange` class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_RANGE", catalog="datasync")
public class AttributeValueRange {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    private String rangeId;

    private String value;

    /**
     * @return the rangeId
     */
    public String getRangeId() {
        return rangeId;
    }

    /**
     * @param rangeId the rangeId to set
     */
    public void setRangeId(String rangeId) {
        this.rangeId = rangeId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the value
     */
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * @param value the value to set
     */
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I have got the following stacktrace for errors

```
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of AttributeValueRange.id; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of AttributeValueRange.id

Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of AttributeValueRange.id

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field AttributeValueRange.id to java.lang.String
```

Please Identify What am I missing here?

I am using ZK framework, Spring & Hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the following changes to the mapping to get it right:

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = java.lang.String.class)
@JoinTable(name="ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_RANGE", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ID"))
@MapKeyColumn (name="RANGE_ID")
@Column(name="VALUE")
private Map<String, String> attributeValueRange = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

`@JoinColumn` represents the ID field of the Entity class which contains this Map field.

`@MapKeyColumn` represents the key column of the Map.

`@Column` represents the value column of the Map.

`@JoinTable` represents the table name which will be created automatically for this Map.

There is no need to create a separate Entity class for this Map.